# Why Filedialogs opens on two differents places?

Tags: python, tkinter

In this program the window is in full, zoomed i would say, if i decrease the window and the maximize again the window on full and then i click the button, i notice that the filedialog opens first on the left and then it's placed immediately on the center, try a couple of times and you will notice this, i hope at least. How to place the filedialog directly on the center avoiding this "flickering" effect? Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
def jpg_png():
    try:
        file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:\\Users\\quaranta\\Desktop')
    
    except AttributeError:
        pass
win = Tk()
win.state('zoomed')

btn_apri_jpg_png = customtkinter.CTkButton(win,text='Apri file',text_font=('Courier',13),text_color='white',fg_color='#00A254',hover_color='#00AF54',width=10,corner_radius=8,command=jpg_png)
btn_apri_jpg_png.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=(20,0),padx=(0,50))
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is customtkinter???

Comment: @itprorh66 it's a library for cool buttons, don't import it for this example, can you help me?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Why are you handling AttributeError?

Comment: @itprorh66 a library trying to improve the visuals of tkinter [customtkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter) another would be [ttkbootstrap](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a customtkinter issue

I tried recreating your problem without using customtkinter (as you stated in your comment to "not import it")

I can't reproduce your flickering with this code. Can you confirm that it still happens without using customtkinter?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def jpg_png():
    try:
        file = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    except AttributeError:
        pass


win = Tk()
win.state('zoomed')

btn_apri_jpg_png = Button(win, text='Apri file', width=10, command=jpg_png)
btn_apri_jpg_png.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=(20, 0), padx=(0, 50))
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, yes it happens even with the code you posted without customtkinter, it's strange because i tried yesterday with my home pc and i did't noticed this issue, it seems that the window is first created on the left and then moved to the center, other suggestions?

Comment: Let's make sure we are talking about the same thing. I'm running this on windows 10 with python 3.10, what about you?